# How to fix an object not to move out of frame in Java?

Tags: java

Fix this code in such way that rectangle does not move out of frame bounds
frame size is (400,400)

```
public void moveRectangle(int dx, int dy) {
    rect.translate(dx * RECT_WIDTH, dy * RECT_HEIGHT);
    repaint();
}
```

Comment: Just increase the value of the rectangle, to a `Math.min(squareposition, 400)`

Comment: `java.lang.Math.min(rectangle_XPosition, Xboundary)` so that if your rectangleposition > your boundary, it will only get to your boundary.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using [java.awt.Rectangle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html), this is the approach I would go for:

```
public void moveRectangle(int dx, int dy) {
    Point location = rect.getLocation();
    Dimension size = rect.getSize();

    // Calculate the maximum dx and dy so the rectangle
    // will not move out of frame
    int dxMax = 400 - size.getWidth() - location.getX();
    int dyMax = 400 - size.getHeight() - location.getY();

    if(dx > dxMax) {
        dx = dxMax;
    }

    if(dy > dyMax) {
        dy = dyMax;
    }

    // Move the rectangle
    rect.translate(dx, dy);
}
```